# How do I stop powershell from echoing my script

Tags: powershell

I'm importing a csv file and looping thru each record and displaying the name. The script works but it also echos the whole script as well. Is there a way to stop that? And is there a reason it happens that way?

```
<# Csv Layout

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx

Name,Department,Title
Pilar Ackerman,Research,Manager
Jonathan Haas,Finance,Finance Specialist
Ken Myer,Finance,Accountant

#>

$vms = Import-Csv c:\temp\test.txt

foreach($vm in $vms){
  $vm.Name  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Save script file.

Comment: doh! nice catch! Make it an answer and i'll check it!

Comment: This is just how ISE works. When you "run" code from the editor is pushes it to console and executes it. You need to save it as a script file and execute it that way. The trade off is you have to save between edits.